Ingress controller not listening on port 5050 for my tcp traffic
I have deployed an application in AKS where I have opened port 5050 for the pod and also created service and ingress to support the same, and configured ingress controller to listen for port 5050 but that is not working. Please guide whether this setup is feasible and how I can open port 5050 for my ingress controller.
I added configmap in nginx-ingress namespace to use tcp traffic, and also added required arguments in the ingress controller.

To ensure Ingress controller not listens on port 5050, configure your setup as below-
nginx-ingress-controller-deployment.yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.0.4
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
          env:
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 443
            - containerPort: 5050


nginx-ingress-controller-service.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
    - name: tcp-5050
      port: 5050
      targetPort: 5050
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress


tcp-services-configmap.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  "5050": "default/nginx-service:5050"


Deploy the application
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            - containerPort: 5050
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "nginx -g 'daemon off;' && while true; do nc -l -p 5050; done"]

service for the application:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5050
      targetPort: 5050
  selector:
    app: nginx



Now do
kubectl get svc -n nginx-ingress


